# AnimatePresence not working with clipPath inset

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to make an animation for when the user closes a modal, but for some reason it doesn't work when the modal is closed. It should close the modal from bottom to top, but the animation doesn't run. Can anyone shed some light on this?

[here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-jasper-7bbzp5?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours testing animation settings using polygon instead of inset, I got exactly the result I wanted. Below is the configuration I used for the animation:

```
export const variants = {
 initial: {
  clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0)',

  transition: { duration: 0.4 },
 },

 animate: {
  clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%)',

  transition: { duration: 0.4, staggerChildren: 0.1 },
 },

 exit: {
  clipPath: 'polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%)',

  transition: { duration: 0.4 },
 },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `AnimatePresence` to work properly, you need to assign a unique `key` attribute / prop to `AnimatePresence`'s direct child element. This is because `AnimatePresence` uses that `key` to keep track of when the element is removed from React tree.

See an example [here](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really forgot to put the key, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Maybe the problem is in the coordinates of the inset, but I can't find a coordinate setting that works.

Comment: @Allan it seems the inset could be the problem. I tried with simpler animations and it worked just fine. Also I changed `AnimatePresence`'s `initial` prop to `true` and made it initially as `opacity: 0` since it will be hidden or non-visible as default anyways.

Comment: Would you know any way to do this same effect even with another element, for example using polygon instead of inset? Thanks!